# NavigationManager injection in WPF appliaction

Tags: c#, wpf, blazor

I am using BlazorWebView in WPF application, an instance of NavigationManager is injected into service class but attempting to add event handlers or access any other members is causing

```
System.InvalidOperationException: ''WebViewNavigationManager' has not been initialized.'
```

Same code runs normally under WebAssembly hosted in Web Browser.
Injecting NavigationManager into a component does work as expected.

Is this scenario not supported ?
Thanks.

Comment: "Is this scenario not supported?" - I would say that it should be. I use the `NavigationManager` inside `BlazorWebView` Win Forms App.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind would be to check that each application is using the same `render-mode`. If the WebAssembly is being ran as `Server` and WPF as `ServerPrerendered` than the WebAssembly may have access to the `NavigationManager` in earlier parts of the page lifecycle. The WebView version I'm using is 6.0.300-rc.2.5513.

Comment: Answer was given here https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8583#event-6959370333

Comment: ahh makes sense. I didn't know you were trying to inject in the `OnStartup`. I wouldn't expect this to work in WebAssembly either but maybe I'm mistaking. Glad you figured it out!